# Is it theoretically possible to run code entered by the user in Swift?

Tags: string, swift

Let's say you have a UITextView, and the user enters Swift code and clicks submit. Is it possible to run this code?
In other words, is it possible to convert a string to runnable code?

Comment: No. There's no `eval` in Swift (thank goodness).

Comment: it depends, I guess... if you implement an own parser and you can interpret own input which can trigger different functionalities in the app. what I mean, you create a parser which can interpret the following line e.g. `The backgound colour should be red.` or `bgcolour = #ff0000`, and the app changes the background colour to the desired one, that can be a kinda acceptable way because your app technically not running external code on the device, but the input triggers some functions of the app – which usually could be triggered by a simple button as well.

Comment: If you can, I suspect it would be through calling [REPL](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=18) in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having researched this, I'm going to say probably not. Swift code is compiled by your computer before it ever reaches the device (just like Objective-C), and an iOS device almost certainly has no built-in means to compile Swift code.

Even if you can include a Swift compiler in your app, I would think you're going to have a hard time convincing iOS to actually *run* your code, as it probably won't be trusted by the system.

I'd like to be proven wrong, though!

Comment: How does the phone run apps from the App Store when not connected to a computer? Isn't the data stored in files in the phone? What if you went into the phone's file system and changed the text in there based on the users input?

Comment: Packages downloaded from the app store are already compiled. It isn't the raw code

Answer (score 1):

You would have to build a swift compiler into your app. Even if this was possible, I would 100% guarantee that Apple would reject any app submitted to the app store that included this feature.

I've seen Android apps that can compile Java code, but this is more because of how JVM works.

Comment: Why would Apple reject this?